# Lodash : Filter with needed attributes only

Tags: javascript, angularjs, lodash

```
 [
  {
    "Office_Id": 100,
    "Address1": "xxxxx",
    "Address2": "",
    "City": "ANNISTON",
    "District_Id": 1277,
    "OfficeName": "test"
  },
  {
    "Office_Id": 200,
     "Address1": "xxxxx",
    "Address2": "",
    "City": "ANNISTON",
    "District_Id": 1277,
    "OfficeName": "test"
  },
  {
    "Office_Id": 300,
     "Address1": "xxxxx",
    "Address2": "",
    "City": "ANNISTON",
    "District_Id": 1277,
    "OfficeName": "test"
  }
]
```

How can i filter with only Office_Id and OfficeName

Comment: You use the word `filter` - I dont think it means what you think it does. Do you want only certain office_id/officename, or do you want all of the objects but with only those two properties?

Comment: you mean you want to strip everything else and keep only those two attributes in all objects? also, share what you have tried so far..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Without lodash (*plain* javascript), like this:**
*(if you want to strip everything except for the two attributes)*

```js
let list = [
  {
    "Office_Id": 100,
    "Address1": "xxxxx",
    "Address2": "",
    "City": "ANNISTON",
    "District_Id": 1277,
    "OfficeName": "test"
  },
  {
    "Office_Id": 200,
     "Address1": "xxxxx",
    "Address2": "",
    "City": "ANNISTON",
    "District_Id": 1277,
    "OfficeName": "test"
  },
  {
    "Office_Id": 300,
     "Address1": "xxxxx",
    "Address2": "",
    "City": "ANNISTON",
    "District_Id": 1277,
    "OfficeName": "test"
  }
];

let newList = list.map(function(currentItem){
    return {"Office_Id": currentItem.Office_Id, "OfficeName": currentItem.OfficeName};
});
console.info(newList);

// Tested on Win7 64bit Chrome 57+
```

> the `map` function of the Array Object, will create a new Array, with the values the past in function returns (in this case `x => {return {"Office_Id": x.Office_Id, "OfficeName": x.OfficeName};}`). Details to the function can be found here [MDN Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?v=example)

As state in the comments you can minimize the code with lambda-functions, destructuring and optimized literal notation. (but check compatability before using each feature, that the news javascript version supports

**Here a short Version:**
`list.map(({Office_Id, OfficeName}) => ({Office_Id, OfficeName})});`

**Update, with lodash:**

```js
let list = [
      {
        "Office_Id": 100,
        "Address1": "xxxxx",
        "Address2": "",
        "City": "ANNISTON",
        "District_Id": 1277,
        "OfficeName": "test"
      },
      {
        "Office_Id": 200,
         "Address1": "xxxxx",
        "Address2": "",
        "City": "ANNISTON",
        "District_Id": 1277,
        "OfficeName": "test"
      },
      {
        "Office_Id": 300,
         "Address1": "xxxxx",
        "Address2": "",
        "City": "ANNISTON",
        "District_Id": 1277,
        "OfficeName": "test"
      }
    ];


let newList = _.map(list, function(value){
  return { "Office_Id": value.Office_Id,"OfficeName": value.OfficeName};
});

console.info(newList);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash-compat/3.10.2/lodash.js"></script>
```

Here the [link to the Documentation of the lodash map function](https://lodash.com/docs/#map)

Comment: `list.map(({Office_Id, OfficeName}) => {return {Office_Id, OfficeName};});`

Comment: @Jamiec do not.

Comment: Yes, is better but i wanted the example not to be to minimalistic. :-D

Comment: @ShriyaR  I updated with lodash, but use a library if it works with a nativ function.

Comment: @winner_joiner Thanks :)